# Cannot see View after adding it to FrameLayout programatically

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am implementing my own version of `VideoView`. The class includes a play-pause button as an `ImageView`, which overlays the `VideoView`. Everything is wrapped by a `FrameLayout`. To use this class, I call a custom initializer method which removes the class from its parent, programatically creates the `FrameLayout` and `ImageView`, then adds the `VideoView` and `ImageView` to the `FrameLayout`. Finally, the `FrameLayout` is added to the parent of the `VideoView` as the original index. The issue is that the view is not visible to the user, although I can see the parent has the FrameLayout as its child when debugging.

```
public class PodoVideoView extends VideoView {

// boilerplate constructors removed

// This method must be called to set the functionality of this class.
// reasoning: cannot call getParent() from constructor
public void init(Activity activity) {

    // remove VideoView and save its index
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) this.getParent();
    int indexInParent = parent.indexOfChild(this);
    parent.removeView(this);

    // setup layout
    final FrameLayout videoViewLayout = new FrameLayout(activity);
    videoViewLayout.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    videoViewLayout.setLayoutParams((new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)));

    // add VideoView and play/pause ImageView to layout
    videoViewLayout.addView(this);
    final ImageView playPauseImageView = new ImageView(activity);
    playPauseImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.video_play);
    videoViewLayout.addView(playPauseImageView);

    // add layout to parent
    parent.addView(videoViewLayout, indexInParent);

    // play/pause UX
    setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
            setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(isPlaying()) {
                        playPauseImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mp.pause(); // if this doesn't work, use mp.pause() instead of pause()
                    } else {
                        playPauseImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            playPauseImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That code looks OK. What color is your `video_play` `Drawable`? You sure it's not just blending in? What type of `ViewGroup` is the parent? Actually, it would help to see the layout XML. Also, any particular reason you don't just do this in the layout?

Answer (score 2):

try `playPauseImageView.bringToFront();`
and you should set the view's `LayoutParams` when you add it to a viewGroup

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
videoViewLayout.addView(playPauseImageView, layoutParams);
playPauseImageView.bringToFront();
```